Why is getInterfaceAddress.getNetworkPrefixLength returns -1 when using any wireguard vpn?
So im trying to get all masks of Ipv4 Addresses in all of netints, but for whatever reason any address inside vpn interface has a networkPrefixLength of -1. Why is it happening? (btw it only happens for windows, linux is fine)
I wrote a couple of functions to retrieve ip info and put them into data classes, but models related to vpn are incorrect:
private suspend fun updateInterfaces() {
        _interfaces.value = withContext(scope.coroutineContext) {
            NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList().map { it.toNetIf() }
                .filter { it.adresses.isNotEmpty() }
        }
    }

fun NetworkInterface.toNetIf(): NetworkInterfaceModel {
    return NetworkInterfaceModel(
        name = name,
        adresses = interfaceAddresses
            .filter { it.address is Inet4Address }
            .map { interfaceAddress ->
                AddressModel(
                    decimalIpAddress = (interfaceAddress.address as Inet4Address).hostAddress,
                    //this returns -1
                    maskPrefixLength = interfaceAddress.networkPrefixLength.toInt() 
                )
            }
    )
}

